# Python: using list comprehension to cycle through a word with an offset (removing one letter at a time)

Tags: python

I am trying to use list comprehension to cycle through the letters in a word and get new combinations after removing one letter at a time.

E.g. say the input string is a word: 'bathe'

I would like to get the output in a list (preferably) with the following
[athe, bthe, bahe, bate]

ie, making just one pass from left to right

---- this is the literal, but I need to accomplish this with list comprehension

word = "bathe"

newlist1 = [word[1::], (word[1:2] + word[-3:]), (word[:2] + word[-2:]), word[:3] + word[-1:]  ]

print('sample 1', newlist1)

newlist2 = [(word[1:2] + word[-3:]), (word[1:2] + word[-3:]), (word[:2] + word[-2:]), word[:3] + word[-1:]  ]

print('sample 2', newlist2)

---

I got through the first pass with this code, but am stuck now

x = [(word[:i] + word[-j:]) for i in range(1,4) for j in range(4,1, -1)]

The output I get is obviously not right, but (hopefully) is directionally there (when it comes to using list comprehensions)

['bathe', 'bthe', 'bhe', 'baathe', 'bathe', 'bahe', 'batathe', 'batthe', 'bathe']

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you click the "Edit" button at the bottom of your question, you can then access the editing help that will provide you with instructions on how to properly format your code samples. That makes them much easier for us to read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First, you need some way to remove a certain element from a list:

```py
def without(lst: list, items: list) -> list:
    """
    Returns a list without anything in the items list
    """
    new_lst = lst.copy()
    for e in lst:
        if e in items:
            items.remove(e)
            new_lst.remove(e)
    return new_lst
```

Then, using that function you can create your new word list.

```py
new_word_list = ["".join(without(list(word), list(letter))) for letter in word]
```

As showed in your wanted output, you don't want the last result of this, so you can just add [:-1] to it.

```py
new_word_list = ["".join(without(list(word), list(letter))) for letter in word][:-1]
```

Another way you could do it (without the `without` function):

```py
new_word_list = [word[:index - 1] + word[index:] for index, _ in enumerate(word)][1:]
```

The `[1:]` at the end is because you end up with a weird string at the beginning (because of the way it is written). The weird string is `bathbathe` (when word is `bathe`)

Comment: thank you!  Do you think there is a way of accomplishing this in a single list comprehension statement? I.e. is there a way to define the function inside list comprehension

Comment: @ZibaJoon Yes, there is. I added it to my answer.